# Predicted values for fixed effect quantile regression

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, quantile-regression

I'm currently working with the method proposed by Koenker (2004) and Lamarche(2010) on fixed effects for quantile regression, for this I'm using the RQPD code in R. I would like to get the predicted values for each firm after running the RQPD code.

The problem is that, after the running the code is only possible to retrieve the residuals. I know that the observed values of Y minus the residuals will give me the predicted values; but I need to run some simulations and for that I need to know how to get the predicted values "by hand" based on the β0 and β1 coefficients.

I tried to get the predicted values as in the OLS: β0 + β1 (x) + the individual effect of the corresponding firm, using the following code:

```
require(rqpd) # it works only for version 2.15.3
set.seed(10)
m <- 3   
n <- 10   
s <- as.factor(rep(1:n,rep(m,n)))   
x <- exp(rnorm(n*m))           
X <- cbind(1,x)
u <- x*rnorm(m*n) + (1-x)*rf(m*n,3,3)
a <- rep(rnorm(n),rep(m,n))      
y <- a + u
fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 1))
summary(fit)
fitcoe<-dcoef(fit)

res<-residuals(fit) # list of 100 residuals, I assumed the following:
res25<-res[1:30] # residuals for the 0.25 quantile
res50<-res[31:60] # residuals for the 0.50 quantile
res75<-res[61:90] # residuals for the 0.75 quantile
FE<-res[91:100] # individual effects for each firm

fitted1<-y-res25 # fitted values for the 0.25 quantile
fit1.1<-fitcoe[1,]+ fitcoe[2,]*x[1]+FE[1] # example for 1st observation
```

Unfortunately this is not working, for example for the first observation: when I substract the residuals from the observed values of Y, I get a predicted value of -0.8690 and when I calculate the predicted values by hand (fit1.1), I get a value of -1.2748. Do I miss something on my way to calculate the predicted values?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a reproducible example. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Although this Q mentions R, it appears to be ultimately about how the predicted values are calculated (not the R code to retrieve them). That may be enough to make it on-topic here.

Comment: If you have a fixed effects model: why do you apply a package explicitly written for models with random effects?

Comment: The package has also an option for fixed effects proposed by Koenker (2004)